# converting an string matrix to numpy ndarray

Tags: python, parsing, integer

considering a matrix like:

> +0.00000E+00    +0.00000E+00\n
> +0.00000E+00    +0.00000E+00\n
> +0.00000E+00    +0.00000E+00

that is originally extracted from a text file, I want to convert it to a numpy ndarray of size 3 by 2 with pure int elements.
I tried simple int function, pickle module and some other methods with no luck.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
string = "+0.00000E+00 +0.00000E+00\n +0.00000E+00 +0.00000E+00\n +0.00000E+00 +0.00000E+00"
array_n = re.findall(r'\S+', string)
array_n = np.array(array_n).astype(float)

array_out = array_n.reshape(3,2)
```

which gives:

```
array([['+0.00000E+00', '+0.00000E+00'],
       ['+0.00000E+00', '+0.00000E+00'],
       ['+0.00000E+00', '+0.00000E+00']], dtype='<U12')
```

Comment: Is the string a row in a matrix or the ouput of reading a txt file? How does it original look like?

Comment: The string is extracted from a text that contains many other fields. The solution worked completely. Just added : "array_n = np.array(array_n).astype(float)" to have desired output . Thank you

Comment: Glad it help!! Happy coding! Mark the answer as accepted if it is what you wanted. I will update it.